# How do I install a new Docky theme?

Tags: themes, docky

How do I install themes for Docky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Download the theme, Right click the docky icon (the anchor icon)
- Click settings,
- Click install next to the theme selection menu,
- Select the theme and click "Select".
- Choose your new theme from the dropdown list.

*P.S. comment if you would like me to post a video tutorial*

*EDIT: If the file is a zip, open it with archive manager, convert it to the correct format, and then install it.*

Comment: ok its working.. but some themes that i download is in zip archive and it cannot install using that way..

Comment: @fly_high_hahaha it's possible that the theme creator but another file inside the zip. Open it to make sure that there is not a bunch of extra stuff inside for you to extract first.